# Using Stored Procedure in Java - Parameter is not an OUT Parameter error

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting this error when calling my stored procedure with an out parameter. It points to where I register the out parameter. I don't see what I'm missing here. Thanks in advance.

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 6 is not an OUT parameter

Here's my method in Java:

```
        String sp = "{CALL `hotelbuddy2.0`.`reservation.newres`(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
        CallableStatement cs = DB2.con2.prepareCall(sp);

        cs.setInt(1, guest.getGuestId());
        cs.setTimestamp(2, checkIn);
        cs.setTimestamp(3, checkOut);
        cs.setString(4, comment);
        cs.setString(5, UserDetails.username);
        cs.registerOutParameter(6, Types.INTEGER);
        cs.execute();
        reservationId = cs.getInt(6);
        cs.close();
```

Here's my Stored Procedure in Mysql:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `reservation.newres`(
IN p_guest_id INT,
IN p_check_in TIMESTAMP,
IN p_check_out timestamp,
IN p_comment VARCHAR(300),
IN p_created_by VARCHAR(45),
OUT p_reservation_id INT
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO reservation
SET guest_id = p_guest_id,
    check_in = p_check_in,
    check_out = p_check_out,
    `comment` = p_comment,
    created_by = p_created_by;

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO p_reservation_id;

END
```

Comment: Can you try `String sp = "{CALL hotelbuddy2.0.reservation.newres(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";` i.e remove quotes. perhaps escape dot.

Comment: Try this: `reservationId = cs.getInt(6);`

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo @PrerakSola. I'll edit that part. The code stops at registering the out parameter. Even if I change the position of the out parameter from 1 to 6 i still get the error - Parameter number x is not an OUT parameter.